# mathematical logic: a step is not clear

Tags: logic

I'm reading the Shoenfield's book *Mathematical Logic*. On page 53 it states:

> Let **r** be the special constant for $\exists x.\neg$A. Then $\exists x. \neg A  \implies \neg A_x[\boldsymbol{r}]$ [substitution of **r** for **x**] is an axiom of $T_c$. Bringing the left-hand side to prenex form and using the tautology theorem,
>
> $$⊢_{T_c} A_x[\boldsymbol{r}] \implies\forall x. A.$$

I do not understand why the author refers to prenex form. Someone can explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*But why does Shoenfield seemingly refer to the first move as "Bringing the left hand side into prenex form"? The left-side is in prenex form already. The operation of dragging the negation of the front Is not making it prenex (by his own standards).*

I agree completely. I think he actually wanted to write something like: "Bringing the left side to the step precedeing the prenex form [i.e. the inversion of prenex operation (b) on page 37, and assuming, with this, the opening of ***A*** - see in this respect the use of the theorem (1) in relation to an open formula in the following Herbrand's theorem]".

*A mystery why he writes that?*

Of course, the mystery will not be solved by the author, since he's gone.

Answer (score 0):

[Corrected version, after comments!]

Evidently $\exists x \neg A \to \neg A_x[\mathbf{r}]$ is an axiom. Bring the quantifier to the front on the l.h.s. and we have
$$\vdash_T \neg \forall x A \to \neg A_x[\mathbf{r}]$$ 
and contraposing (which we allowed to do by "using the tautology theorem") we get
$$\vdash_T A_x[\mathbf{r}] \to \forall x A$$

But why does Shoenfield seemingly refer to the first move as "bringing the left hand side into prenex form"? The left-side *is* in prenex form already. The operation of dragging the negation of the front isn't making it prenex (by his own standards). A mystery why he writes that?

Comment: I think it's confusing because $\exists x \neg A$ looks more prenex to me than $\neg \forall x A$ does. (But I suppose one could define "prenex" to mean "formula begins with a string of $\neg$ and $\forall$ and is otherwise quantifier-free", where I'm used to "formula begins with a string of $\exists$ and $\forall$ and is otherwise quantifier-free").

Comment: I received this observation also:

_I think he may have in mind just the negation Bringing out through the sign exists (this is what you do When proving prenex normal form) and then deducing the contrapositive._

I too had thought of this, but the exposition of the text is not clear (literally, "prenex form" refers to an entire formula: those who say that ***A*** is prenex?)

In addition, according to the definition of the book, "prenex form" is when there is only a prefix consisting of only quantifiers: thus $\neg$$\forall x A$ does not fall into that category.

Comment: I received this observation also:

_I think he may have in mind just bringing the negation  out through the sign exists (this is what you do when proving prenex normal form) and then deducing the contrapositive._

I too had thought of this, but the exposition of the text is not clear (literally, "prenex form" refers to an entire formula: those who say that ***A*** is prenex?)

In addition, according to the definition of the book, "prenex form" is when there is only a prefix consisting of only quantifiers: thus $\neg$$\forall x A$ does not fall into that category.

Comment: I forgot to thank you very much for your reply and  comments.

Comment: Oooops I really really wasn't concentrating in my initial answer there -- taking my eye of the ball because of the misplaced negations in the uncorrected version?? Henning is quite right, I misused "prenex". But then it seems that Shoenfield did too, given what he says earlier now I've checked.